# If $UA U^\dagger=A$ for all real matrices $A$ is $U$ the identity?

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ is an arbitrary real $d \times d$ matrix, $A \in M_{d \times d}(\mathbb R)$ and $U$ is a fixed $d \times d$ unitary matrix, $U \in U(d)$. If $$UA U^\dagger=A$$ for all $A \in M_{d \times d}(\mathbb R)$ can we conclude that $U=I$? That is, $U$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: No. For instance, $U$ could be any unitary scalar matrix.

Comment: @carmichael561 Can you define what you mean by unitary scalar matrix? I am not familiar with this term.

Comment: @Alex: A scalar matrix has the form $\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. A unitary scalar matrix is just a scalar matrix which happens to be unitary, so $\lambda I$ with $|\lambda|=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is a $d \times d$ matrix (over $\mathbb C$) such that $U A U^\dagger = A$ for all $d \times d$ real matrices.
Taking $A = I$, we find that $U$ must be unitary.  Taking $A$ with a single entry $A_{ij} = 1$, all the rest $0$, we find that $U = \lambda I$ where $|\lambda|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can have $U = \lambda I$ for any $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ such that $|\lambda| = 1$.

Note that the equation can be rearranged to yield
$$
UAU^\dagger = A \implies UA = AU
$$
It is well known that any matrix $U$ such that $AU = UA$ for *all* matrices $A$ must be a multiple of the identity matrix.  Note that $\lambda I$ is unitary if and only if $|\lambda| = 1$.